# Can`t MAX() function be used with mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, max

I can not find a proper answer to this question. I have a very simple code for making a query in mysql to select the row with the maximum value in a determined column (called popularity) from a table (called comments). Every row has a column named comment_id

here is the code:

$connect_error = 'Sorry, try again, there was a connection error';

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user_name','password') or die($connect_error);

mysqli_select_db($con, 'database') or die($connect_error);

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT MAX(`popularity`) FROM `comments`");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $most_popular = $row['comment_id'];             
            }

    echo "most popular is: $most_popular";

        mysqli_free_result($result);

        mysqli_close($con);
```

the screen does not show a proper result. Can someone give me an advice in this regard?

Thank you

Comment: Is the 'popularity' column a numeric value?

Comment: 1) What results are you getting?
2) Shouldn't those backticks be single quotes? i.e. 'popularity' rather than `popularity`
3) try doing a `echo $con->error` after your query statement to see if there's any errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking to display the `comment_id` field, but you don't have that in your `SELECT` query. You are only selecting the max `popularity` value, and nothing else.

Try this for your query:

```
SELECT comment_id FROM comments ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 1
```

This is sorting your comments by popularity, and then just picking the top one.

Of course you can easily change that to select more columns or even a `SELECT *` if you want to be able to display other values in this record.

Comment: @RaymondN which is why I didn't state that as my primary answer. but really, a downvote??

Comment: Alway having stackoverflow on two screens, accidentally pushed down the vote down when i switched to fast... voted back up again and i removed my answer what should be correct in this case because you downvoted too get even...

Answer (score 1):

To select the row with max 'popularity' column use this query;

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY `popularity` DESC LIMIT 1");
```

In case you want all sorted by popularity remove the LIMIT 1...

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
SELECT MAX(`popularity`) AS comment_id FROM `comments`
```

This will give the column the correct name for the associated array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to read the result from a column named `comment_id` when the result from your query will be named `MAX(popularity)`

Answer (score 0):

Run this query in mysql "SELECT MAX(`popularity`) FROM `comments`" first.The output of this gives you the index to use with $row[`index`] ie first row which in this case the index will be `popularity` else just change $row[`content_id`] to $row[`popularity`]